# Comparison Operators not working correctly in mysqli prepare statement on WAMP

Tags: php, mysqli, wamp, wampserver

I had my website on a hosting site, and everything was working fine, except I was going over my allowed cpu usage. I migrated my website and database to my local machine where I have WAMP installed.

**Old Host:**
Apache version  *2.2.23*
PHP version     *5.3.18*
MySQL version   *5.1.66-cll*

**WAMP:**
Apache *2.4.2*
PHP *5.4.3*
MYSQL *5.5.24*

For some reason, the less than and greater than comparison operators stopped working in my mysqli prepare statement. If I remove the following part of the sql statement then it returns EVERYTHING fine like it should. I also tried manually typing in a date manually where the ? is, and that also returned correctly.

**DOES NOT WORK** `where last_update > ?`

**DOES WORK** `where last_update > '1991-09-26 01:25:10'`

Here is the code that I have:

```
<?php

session_start();

$output = "You must log in to see users.";

if (isset($_SESSION['status'])){

    $status = $_SESSION['status'];
    $myUsername = $_SESSION['username'];

    if ($status == 1){

        $output = "";

        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
        $mysqli = new DB_CONNECT();

        $currentTime2 = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 seconds'));

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select username from users where last_update > ? order by username")){

            $stmt->bind_param("s", $currentTime2);

            $username = "";

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($username);

            while ($stmt->fetch()){
                if ($username != $myUsername){
                    $output = $output . "<div class='user'><div class='user-pic'></div><div class='user-name'>" . $username . "</div></div>";
                }
            }

            $stmt->close();

        }
    }
}

echo $output;

?>
```

The only error I get from that php file is:

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Strict standards: Declaration of DB_CONNECT::connect() should be compatible with mysqli::connect($host = NULL, $user = NULL, $password = NULL, $database = NULL, $port = NULL, $socket = NULL) in C:\wamp\www\db_connect.php on line 31
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  254240  {main}( )   ..\onlineUsers.php:0
```

Here is the db_connect.php file:

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT extends mysqli{

    function __construct() {

        $this->connect();
    }

    function __destruct() {

        $this->close();
    }

    function connect() {

        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        parent::__construct(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
    }

    function close() {

    }

}

?>
```

Note that I get this if i use bind_param or just manually enter a datetime, so it's probably not the cause here.

Comment: No error for the bind. I will update above.

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean? Is it ignoring the comparison and returning all rows, returning no rows, or returning an error from `execute`?

Comment: It is returning no rows. Every file that I have like this, is returning no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue myself. After echoing the time from $currentTime2, I noticed it was 5 hours in the future. I am in UTC-0:500 time, so I changed my php.ini file at the line for date.timezone.

`date.timezone = "America/New_York"`

Answer (score 0):

> .1. I also tried manually typing in a date manually where the ? is, and that also returned correctly.
>
> .2. Note that I get this if i use bind_param or just manually enter a datetime, so it's probably not the cause here.

... looks like contradicts each one, eh?

It seems that there is a slight difference between time passed since 1991-09-26 01:25:10 and 15 seconds. I have a feeling that you have to double-check your *data*, if it meets such a strict condition.

Comment: The data is fine as it was working on the server. When somebody logs in, javascript is updating their entry in the db for last_update every 5 seconds. I use this field to check that they are still online in case they close their browser window. I seemed to have fixed my issue by changing my timezone in the php.ini file.